# How to zoom ImageView inside PageViewController swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am using a `PageViewController` which loads multiple images. I can slide through the images one by one. I now want to zoom that `ImageView`, how can I achieve it. Thanks in advance.

I have this in my **viewDidLoad**

```
var vWidth = self.view.frame.width
var vHeight = self.view.frame.height

var scrollImg: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
scrollImg.delegate = self
scrollImg.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, vWidth, vHeight)
scrollImg.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 90, green: 90, blue: 90, alpha: 0.90)
scrollImg.alwaysBounceVertical = false
scrollImg.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
scrollImg.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
scrollImg.flashScrollIndicators()

scrollImg.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
scrollImg.maximumZoomScale = 10.0

self.view.addSubview(scrollImg)

scrollImg.addSubview(contentImageView!)
```

And then the delegate of the **scrollview**

```
func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return self.contentImageView
    }
```

Now the image gets kind of zoomed abnormally, focusing mostly on the top. And not able to pan it.

Comment: Add UIScrollView inside the pageViewController's view and imageView as a subview to the scrollView. Implement scrollview's delegate viewForZoomingInRect, and set minimumZoomScale and maximumZoomScale to the scrollView and that should do it.

Comment: viewForZooming in rect ?

Comment: Oh sorry, it should be rather viewForZoomingInScrollView

Comment: No prob. Still there are some problems. Please check my edit.